# TypeError: 'Vector' object is not iterable

Tags: python, vector, typeerror

I was trying to compute the intersection point of two lines, but constantly get "TypeError: 'Vector' object is not iterable"
I've tried to search for the answer but failed. How should I fix this, pls?

## here's the code:

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

from vector import Vector

getcontext().prec = 30


class Line(object):

    NO_NONZERO_ELTS_FOUND_MSG = 'No nonzero elements found'

    def __init__(self, normal_vector=None, constant_term=None):
        self.dimension = 2

        if not normal_vector:
            all_zeros = ['0']*self.dimension
            normal_vector = Vector(all_zeros)
        self.normal_vector = normal_vector

        if not constant_term:
            constant_term = Decimal('0')
        self.constant_term = Decimal(constant_term)

        self.set_basepoint()

    def __eq__(self, ell):
        if self.normal_vector.is_zero():
            if not ell.normal_vector.is_zero():
                return False
            else:
                diff = self.constant_term - ell.constant_term
                return MyDecimal(diff).is_near_zero()
        elif ell.normal_vector.is_zero():
            return False

        if not self.is_parallel_to(ell):
            return False

        x0 = self.basepoint
        y0 = ell.basepoint
        basepoint_difference = x0.minus(y0)

        n = self.normal_vector
        return basepoint_difference.is_orthogonal_to(n)

    def is_parallel_to(self, ell):
        n1 = self.normal_vector
        n2 = ell.normal_vector
        return n1.is_parallel_to(n2)

    def set_basepoint(self):
        try:
            n = self.normal_vector
            c = self.constant_term
            basepoint_coords = ['0']*self.dimension

            initial_index = Line.first_nonzero_index(n)
            initial_coefficient = n[initial_index]

            basepoint_coords[initial_index] = c/initial_coefficient
            self.basepoint = Vector(basepoint_coords)

        except Exception as e:
            if str(e) == Line.NO_NONZERO_ELTS_FOUND_MSG:
                self.basepoint = None
            else:
                raise e

    def intersection_with(self, ell):
        try:
            A, B = self.normal_vector.coordinates
            C, D = ell.normal_vector.coordinates
            k1 = self.constant_term
            k2 = ell.constant_term

            x_numerator = D*k1 - B*k2
            y_numerator = -C*k1 + A*k2
            one_over_denom = Decimal('1')/(A*D - B*C)

            return Vector([x_numerator, y_numerator]).times_scalar(one_over_denom)

        except ZeroDivisionError:
            if self == ell:
                return self
            else:
                return None

    def __str__(self):

        num_decimal_places = 3

        def write_coefficient(coefficient, is_initial_term=False):
            coefficient = round(coefficient, num_decimal_places)
            if coefficient % 1 == 0:
                coefficient = int(coefficient)

            output = ''

            if coefficient < 0:
                output += '-'
            if coefficient > 0 and not is_initial_term:
                output += '+'

            if not is_initial_term:
                output += ' '

            if abs(coefficient) != 1:
                output += '{}'.format(abs(coefficient))

            return output

        n = self.normal_vector

        try:
            initial_index = Line.first_nonzero_index(n)
            terms = [write_coefficient(n[i], is_initial_term=(i==initial_index)) + 'x_{}'.format(i+1)
                     for i in range(self.dimension) if round(n[i], num_decimal_places) != 0]
            output = ' '.join(terms)

        except Exception as e:
            if str(e) == self.NO_NONZERO_ELTS_FOUND_MSG:
                output = '0'
            else:
                raise e

        constant = round(self.constant_term, num_decimal_places)
        if constant % 1 == 0:
            constant = int(constant)
        output += ' = {}'.format(constant)

        return output


    @staticmethod
    def first_nonzero_index(iterable):
        for k, item in enumerate(iterable):
            if not MyDecimal(item).is_near_zero():
                return k
        raise Exception(Line.NO_NONZERO_ELTS_FOUND_MSG)


class MyDecimal(Decimal):
    def is_near_zero(self, eps=1e-10):
        return abs(self) < eps

ell1 = Line(normal_vector = Vector(['4.046', '2.836']), constant_term = '1.21')
ell2 = Line(normal_vector = Vector(['10.115', '7.09']), constant_term = '3.025')
print 'intersection 1:', ell1.intersection_with(ell2)

ell1 = Line(normal_vector = Vector(['7.204', '3.182']), constant_term = '8.68')
ell2 = Line(normal_vector = Vector(['8.172', '4.114']), constant_term = '9.883')
print 'intersection 2:', ell1.intersection_with(ell2)

ell1 = Line(normal_vector = Vector(['1.182', '5.562']), constant_term ='6.744')
ell2 = Line(normal_vector = Vector(['1.773', '8.343']), constant_term = '9.525')
print 'intersection 3:', ell1.intersection_with(ell2)
```

=============================================================

## here's the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Tristan/Desktop/line.py", line 146, in <module>
    ell1 = Line(normal_vector = Vector(['4.046', '2.836']), constant_term = '1.21')
  File "/Users/Tristan/Desktop/line.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.set_basepoint()
  File "/Users/Tristan/Desktop/line.py", line 67, in set_basepoint
    raise e
TypeError: 'Vector' object is not iterable
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/Tristan/Desktop/line.py"]
[dir: /Users/Tristan/Desktop]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

=============================================================

## and here's the code in vector.py:

```
from math import sqrt, acos, pi
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

getcontext().prec = 30

class Vector(object):

    CANNOT_NORMALIZE_ZERO_VECTOR_MSG = 'cannot nomalize the zero vector.'
    CANNOT_COMPUTE_ANGLE_WITH_ZERO_VECTOR_MSG = 'Cannot compute an angle\
                                             with the zero vector.'
    NO_UNIQUE_PARALLEL_COMPONENT_MSG = 'there is no unique parallel\
                                     commponent.'
    NO_UNIQUE_ORTHOGONAL_COMPONENT_MSG = 'there is no unique orthogonal\
                                     commponent.'

    def __init__(self, coordinates):
        try:
            if not coordinates:
                raise ValueError
            self.coordinates = tuple([Decimal(x) for x in coordinates])
            self.dimension = len(self.coordinates)

        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError('The coordinates must be nonempty')

        except TypeError:
            raise TypeError('The coordinates must be an iterable')


    def __str__(self):
        return 'Vector: {}'.format(self.coordinates)

    def __eq__(self, v):
        return self.coordinates == v.coordinates

    def plus(self, v):
        new_coordinates = [x + y for x,y in zip(self.coordinates, v.coordinates)]
        return Vector(new_coordinates)

    def minus(self, v):
        new_coordinates = [x - y for x,y in zip(self.coordinates, v.coordinates)]
        return Vector(new_coordinates)

    def times_scalar(self, c):
        new_coordinates =[Decimal(c)*x for x in self.coordinates]
        return Vector(new_coordinates)

    def magnitude(self):
        coordinates_squared = [x**2 for x in self.coordinates]
        return Decimal(sum(coordinates_squared)).sqrt()

    def normalized(self):
        try:
            magnitude = self.magnitude()
            return self.times_scalar(Decimal('1.0')/Decimal(magnitude))
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            raise Exception(self.CANNOT_NORMALIZE_ZERO_VECTOR_MSG)

    def dot(self, v):
        return sum([x*y for x, y in zip(self.coordinates, v.coordinates)])

    def angle_with(self, v, in_degrees = False):
        try:
            u1 = self.normalized()
            u2 = v.normalized()
            angle_in_radians = Decimal(acos(u1.dot(u2)))

            if in_degrees:
                degrees_per_radian = Decimal('180.0')/Decimal(pi)
                return angle_in_radians * degrees_per_radian
            else:
                return angle_in_radians

        except Exception as e:
            if str(e) == self.CANNOT_NORMALIZE_ZERO_VECTOR_MSG:
                raise Exception(self.CANNOT_COMPUTE_ANGLE_WITH_ZERO_VECTOR_MSG)
            else:
                raise e

    def is_orthogonal_to(self, v, tolerance = 1e-10):
        return abs(self.dot(v)) < tolerance

    def is_parallel_to(self, v):
        return (self.is_zero() 
                or v.is_zero() or 
                self.angle_with(v) == 0 or 
                self.angle_with(v) == pi)

    def is_zero(self, tolerance = 1e-10):
        return self.magnitude() < tolerance

    def projection(self, v):
        try:
            unit_v = v.normalized()
            return (unit_v).times_scalar(self.dot(unit_v))
        except Exception as e:
            if str(e) == self.CANNOT_NORMALIZE_ZERO_VECTOR_MSG:
                raise Exception(self.NO_UNIQUE_PARALLEL_COMPONENT_MSG)
            else:
                raise e

    def orthogonal(self, v):
        try:
            return self.minus(self.projection(v))
        except Exception as e:
            if str(e) == self.NO_UNIQUE_PARALLEL_COMPONENT_MSG:
                raise Exception(self.NO_UNIQUE_ORTHOGONAL_COMPONENT_MSG)
            else:
                raise e

    def decompose(self, v):
        return str(self.projection(v)) + '+' + str(self.orthogonal(v))

    def cross_products(self, v):
        try:
            x_1, y_1, z_1 = self.coordinates
            x_2, y_2, z_2 = v.coordinates
            new_coordinates = [y_1*z_2 - y_2*z_1,
                -(x_1*z_2 - x_2*z_1), x_1*y_2 - x_2*y_1]
            return Vector(new_coordinates)

        except ValueError as e:
            msg = str(e)
            if msg == 'need more than 2 values to unpack':
                self_embedded_in_R3 = Vector(self.coordinates + ('0',))
                v_embedded_in_R3 = Vector(v.coordinates + ('0',))
                return self_embedded_in_R3.cross_products(v_embedded_in_R3)
            elif (msg == 'too many values to unpack' or
                msg == 'need more than 1 value to unpack'):
                raise Exception('only defined in two 3-dimensions')
            else:
                raise e

    def area_of_parallelogram(self, v):
        return (self.cross_products(v)).magnitude()

    def area_of_triangle(self, v):
        return self.area_of_parallelogram(v)/Decimal('2.0')
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you try to minimize the required code yourself (see [mcve]) and [edit] your question? Currently that's just a huge code dump.

Comment: thanks, I will stick to that rule from now on.

Answer (score 3):

The error is coming from the following line in `set_basepoint` function:

```
TypeError: 'Vector' object is not iterable
> test.py(136)first_nonzero_index()
    135     def first_nonzero_index(iterable):
--> 136         for k, item in enumerate(iterable):
    137             if not MyDecimal(item).is_near_zero():

ipdb> up
> test.py(57)set_basepoint()
     56 
---> 57         initial_index = Line.first_nonzero_index(n)
     58         initial_coefficient = n[initial_index]
```

Meaning the line raising exception is `initial_index = Line.first_nonzero_index(n)`.

The line with the error was hidden because of the overly broad try/except block in `set_basepoint`, which I commented out to get to the above.

I am not sure what was wanted there, perhaps `Line.first_nonzero_index(n.coordinates)` instead which does not break.

The code in `first_nonzero_index` is doing `for k, item in enumerate(iterable):` and `iterable` was a `Vector` which is not an iterable, hence the error.

In general, keep try/except blocks as small as possible so as not to hide the code that actually raised the exception.

Also checking `str(e)` equality in exception handling is bad practice, that will break if the string representation of the exception changes. Use `isinstance` on the exception class instead.

Comment: Well said.  I was just typing up my own version of this, but you've now said everything I was planning to say.

Comment: Thank you danny, but after this modification, there rises another error, it reads "TypeError: 'Vector' object does not support indexing".

Comment: @Eric, a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will need to be shown when asking questions. 'Does not support' indexing is the error raised when doing things like `n[1]` on an object that.. does not support indexing, much like the previous iteration error. From that, and the above guidelines on error handling, it should be easy to understand where that error is coming from.

Comment: @danny Problem solved, thanks!  BTW this is my first question on stackoverflow.  I will enhance my way of asking question according to the rules from now on.

Comment: No problem, glad it is resolved and welcome to Stack Overflow. Also please accept an answer if it solved the question, or editing your question with a solution you have found.

Answer (score 0):

```
    def set_basepoint(self):
    try:
        n = self.normal_vector
        # print(n)  # Vector: (Decimal('4.046'), Decimal('2.836'))
        c = self.constant_term
        basepoint_coords = ['0']*self.dimension

        initial_index = Line.first_nonzero_index(n.coordinates)
        # print(initial_index)  # 0

        initial_coefficient = n.coordinates[initial_index]
        # print(initial_coefficient)  # 4.046
        basepoint_coords[initial_index] = c/initial_coefficient
        self.basepoint = Vector(basepoint_coords)

    except Exception as e:
        if str(e) == Line.NO_NONZERO_ELTS_FOUND_MSG:
            self.basepoint = None
        else:
            raise e
```

solve this bug,we should first learn Vector class seriously.

Answer (score 0):

Vector type is not iterable because of

```
 def __str__(self):
        return 'Vector: {}'.format(self.coordinates)
```

the str method actually stores a string not a tuple.

the fix be using `Line.first_nonzero_index(n.coordinates)` instead of `Line.first_nonzero_index(n.coordinates)` in all the instances of calling  first_nonzero_index() and `initial_coefficient = n.coordinates[initial_index]` instead of `initial_coefficient = n[initial_index]`. also, there is another bug

in Line class

in the str method :

```
try:
    initial_index = Line.first_nonzero_index(n.coordinates)
   terms = [write_coefficient(n[i], is_initial_term=(i==initial_index))+'x_{}'.format(i+1)
       for i in range(self.dimension) if round(n.coordinates[i], num_decimal_places) != 0]
            output = ' '.join(terms)
```

vector class is also not indexable do replace each **n** witn **n.coordinates**